# How To Find Middle Numbers On Array

Tags: python, arrays

i try to design program like a game.

So i have a array on python its;
Arrays = [1, 2, 5, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 888, 999, 1000]

When i was starting the program its need to be work as find of middle on array and ask himself it number is bigger then typed number by us. Or smaller? So we say we started the program its would be start as like that;

- data < 60 (middle of arrays)
- typed number is bigger ? < if it is make the selection at 60 to the 1000
  so 60 and 1000 numbers has have a middle ?
- 888 it is my selected number ? if yes so finded congratulations , if its doesn't
- it asking himself the array number is bigger or smaller than typed value?

its actually little complicated.

my problem is if the program will noticed array number is smaller than value giving the wrong numbers:

```
elif ortalen > index:
    ortalen = int((minlen + ortalen)/2)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
Array = [1, 2, 5, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 888, 999, 1000]
searchFor = 888
minlen = 0
maxlen = len(Array)
ortalen = int((maxlen/2))
index = 0
while True:
    index += 1
    bum = Array[index]
    if bum == searchFor:
        break
    else:
        pass
while True:
    #60
    ortasayi = Array[ortalen]
    if ortasayi == searchFor:
        print("congratulations.")
        break
    elif ortalen < index:
        ortalen = int((maxlen + ortalen)/2)
    elif ortalen > index:
        ortalen = int((minlen + ortalen)/2)
```

Comment: Your posted code appears to work: you ask it to find `888`, and it prints `congratulations.` upon finding the number.  For you to receive help, we need to you clearly show the problem, and to give us the code that produces that problem.

Comment: a =888
arrays=[10,20,30,40,50,600,700,888,999,1000]
Lets say we have a variables like that the program need to find a variable. At the start find the middle of the "arrays"  variable, say that variable 50 because it is middle of the array 50 is on the index "4" and program says "50 is bigger than a variable?" to ask his self not the client. if its smaller. Program start to find middle of 50 - 1000 and its "700" later that ask him self its bigger? Or smaller? If smaller program start to find middle of 700-1000 and program find the 888 and thats it "congratulations" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#new program

array= [2, 5, 1, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 888, 999, 1000]
searchFor = 1000
array.sort()
array_uzunlugu = len(array)
array_baslangic = (array_uzunlugu - array_uzunlugu)
array_yarisi = int((len(array)/2))

orta_deger = array[array_yarisi]
while True:
    print(array_yarisi)
    orta_deger = array[array_yarisi]
    if orta_deger < searchFor:
        make = True             
        array_eski = array_yarisi
        try:
            if bum == True:
                array_yarisi = int((array_yarisi + array_eski2)/2)
        except:
            array_yarisi = int((array_yarisi + array_uzunlugu)/2)
    elif orta_deger > searchFor:
        try:
            if make == True:
                array_yarisi = int((array_yarisi+array_eski)/2)
        except:
                bum = True
                array_eski2 = array_yarisi
                array_yarisi = int((array_yarisi)/2)
    elif orta_deger == searchFor:
        print("tebrikler.")
        break
```